# How do 2D arrays with the second dimension empty work?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble understanding the following code:

```
String [][] abc = new String [4][];
```

Would this create the 2d array of 4 rows but each row is empty? Is an initial value given for each row? If each row gets a specific number of rows, what would the initial value be?

Comment: Have you tried it and seen what happens?

Answer (score 0):

It will create a 2d array and each row will be `null`. The following code:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String [][] abc = new String [4][];
      for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
          System.out.println("Element " + i + " has value " + abc[i]);
      }
    }
```

Will output:

```
Element 0 has value null
Element 1 has value null
Element 2 has value null
Element 3 has value null
```